# JetBrains Rider hangs when creating solution file on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, rider

JetBrains Rider hangs indefinitely when creating solution file on Ubuntu 16.04. Already restarted both Rider and my system.

Comment: Probably msbuild was not able to load created project... Today I have received this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-23181

Comment: You can check log files: Help -> Show logs in... -> backend.log

Comment: Look for 'MsBuild' keyword =)

Comment: Where can I find the logs? - OK I think I know.

Comment: There is no entry "MsBuild" in syslog. And there is no backend.log in /var/log directory.

Comment: The issue, you refer to - I don't see any solution in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to bypass this problem by choosing `ASP.NET Web Application` instead of `Empty Solution`.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same issue (OS = Arch Linux). I'd also installed the dot net sdk and Rider from Snap. I had to:

1. Remove Rider using `snapd remove rider`
2. Install dotnet-sdk using `sudo pacman -S dotnet-sdk`
3. Install mono using `sudo pacman -S mono`
4. Download and install the Jetbrains Toolbox app and install Rider from there

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found that my virtual machine did not have Mono installed. Killing and restarting the `Rider` process and selecting another project type prompted me to install mono using this URL: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-debian

With Mono installed I had to restart `Rider` once more before it would let me create an empty solution without hanging.

Comment: It was the actual reason of the issue for me as well, and this is the actual fix that works for me, thanks. `sudo apt install mono-devel` that's all